# Converting complex result set from stored procedure into entities and their children

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure that returns a series of joined table results as one of several result sets, ala:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    at.*
FROM
    dbo.UserProfile up
JOIN
    dbo.Players p ON up.UserId = p.UserId
JOIN
    dbo.PlayerAbilities pa ON p.PlayerId = pa.PlayerId
JOIN
    dbo.Abilities a ON pa.AbilityId = a.AbilityId
JOIN
    dbo.Attributes at ON a.AttributeId = at.AttributeId
WHERE
    up.UserName = @userName
```

My entity class structure for the Ability class is as follows:

```
class Ability
{
    /* Standard Properties */

    public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

When I call this stored procedure with code:

```
//Establish that var reader = (stored procedure).ExecuteReader()
var abilities = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Ability>(reader);
```

I get a collection of Ability objects but their Attribute property is not populated.  How can I modify my stored procedure or instruct entity framework to allow for this property to be populated?

EDIT: Attribute and Ability Table schemas as requested:

```
TABLE Attributes
{
    AttributeId INT PKEY
    AttributeName VARCHAR(50)
}
TABLE Abilities
{
    AbilityId INT PKEY
    AbilityName VARCHAR(50)
    AbilityDescription VARCHAR(500)
    AttributeId INT FKEY => Attributes.AttributeId
    ClassificationId INT FKEY => Classifications.ClassificationId
    BaseDamage INT
    LevelRequired INT
    PriceId INT FKEY => Prices.PriceId
    RecordStatusId INT FKEY => RecordStatuses.RecordStatusId
}
```

Forgot to add this in the original edit:

```
class Attribute
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }

    //Never used, doesn't matter for lazy loading though, never got around to deleting
    public virtual ICollection<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Monster> Monsters1 { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't originally include classification/price/recordstatus column information in the above properties problem because I though it would be redundant, but I've included them here in case it's relevant.

Comment: Can you show us code for class `Attribute` and schema for tables `Attributes` and `Abilities`?

Comment: I've updated it.  There are a couple other entities that would be populated, but I left them out of the original post because they were slightly redundant.  Also, I'll point out that this is only one record set that is coming back from the stored procedure.  It is making 5 selects in case that is relevant at all; based on this tutorial from microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Translate does not know how to deal with navigation properties but if query attributes in a separate query and EF should fix up relationships.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a single query?  The reason I moved to a stored procedure was for performance reasons and doing back and forths kind of works against that.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a stored proc - neither translate nor built-in stored proc handling supports materializing graphs. You should be able to do this with a single linq query using `.Include`. There is not enough information in your question to answer why `.Inlcude` was slow but maybe you should show your original Linq query and describe the scenario and maybe it will be  possible to change the query so that it is faster? Also what are your performance results and expectations? I don't think that for your model Linq query should be really that slow.

Comment: I know it's a late reply, but the underlying data structure was actually quite a bit more complex than what I wrote here, there are several nested entities.  That being said, I converted my query to utilize eager loading and tested it out on some better hardware and it appears to run just fine.